# In Array of Structure why strcmp function is not working for string?

Tags: c, comparison, c-strings, fgets, strcmp

> I want the user to enter "M" for Male or "F" for Female and the single character must be replaced by Male or Female but here the strcmp function is not working everytime time it is showing "Please enter correct value for Gender!!".

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

struct student{
    char name[50];
    int Roll_No;
    char Gender[10];
};

int main()
{
    int size;
    printf("Enter the size for number of students you want to store:");
    scanf("%d",&size);
    struct student s[size];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the name of student s[%d]:",i);
        fflush(stdin);
        fgets(s[i].name,50,stdin);
        printf("Enter the Roll Number of student s[%d]:",i);
        scanf("%d",&s[i].Roll_No);
        gen:printf("Enter your Gender(M-Male F-Female) for student s[%d]:",i);
        fflush(stdin);
        fgets(s[i].Gender,10,stdin);
    
        if(strcmp(s[i].Gender,"M")==0)
        {
            strcpy(s[i].Gender,"Male");
        }
        if(strcmp(s[i].Gender,"F")==0)
        {
            strcpy(s[i].Gender,"Female");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Please enter correct value for Gender!!\n");
            goto gen;
        }
    }
    printf("\nInformation entered of Students:\n");
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        printf("Name of student s[%d]:%s",i,s[i].name);
        printf("Roll Number of student s[%d]:%d\n",i,s[i].Roll_No);
        printf("Gender of student s[%d]:%s\n",i,s[i].Gender);
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is Undefined behavior.

Comment: That said, why do you want to use `strcmp()`? Read the user input in a `char` and compare against `'M'` or `'F'` using `==`. Then, based on result, do `strcpy()`.

Comment: `struct student s[size];` in your C program doesn't compile. Array size must be a constant.

Comment: I used strcmp to make M to Male and F to Female

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed your code. There was a number of errors.

- You flush stdin
- You mix scanf() and fgets()
- Missing else when checking for "F"

There are other areas where to code could be enhanced. I let it as an exercise for you :-)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

struct student {
    char name[50];
    int Roll_No;
    char Gender[10];
};

int main()
{
    int size;
    struct student s[100];
    int i;
    char buf[100];
    printf("Enter the size for number of students you want to store:");
    fgets(buf, 100, stdin);
    sscanf(buf, "%d", &size);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the name of student s[%d]:", i);
        fgets(s[i].name, 50, stdin);
        printf("Enter the Roll Number of student s[%d]:", i);
        fgets(buf, 10, stdin);
        sscanf(buf, "%d", &s[i].Roll_No);
    gen:printf("Enter your Gender(M-Male F-Female) for student s[%d]:", i);
        fgets(buf, 10, stdin);
        sscanf(buf, "%s", s[i].Gender);

        if (strcmp(s[i].Gender, "M") == 0)
        {
            strcpy(s[i].Gender, "Male");
        }
        else if (strcmp(s[i].Gender, "F") == 0)
        {
            strcpy(s[i].Gender, "Female");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Please enter correct value for Gender!!\n");
            goto gen;
        }
    }
    printf("\nInformation entered of Students:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("Name of student s[%d]:%s", i, s[i].name);
        printf("Roll Number of student s[%d]:%d\n", i, s[i].Roll_No);
        printf("Gender of student s[%d]:%s\n", i, s[i].Gender);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `fgets` can append the entered string with the new line character `'\n'` that you should remove.

For example

```
    fgets(s[i].Gender,10,stdin);
    s[i].Gender[ strcspn( s[i].Gender, "\n" ) ] = '\0';

    if(strcmp(s[i].Gender,"M")==0)
    {
        strcpy(s[i].Gender,"Male");
    }
    if(strcmp(s[i].Gender,"F")==0)
    {
        strcpy(s[i].Gender,"Female");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Please enter correct value for Gender!!\n");
        goto gen;
    }
```

Pay attention to that instead of the using the `goto` statement you could enclose the code in the do-while statement.

Also to enter a letter there is no great sense to use the function `fgets` moreover when the entered string will be overwritten.

You could use an object of the type char and use a call of `scanf` like this

```
char gender;

scanf( " %c", &gender );
```

And then

```
if ( toupper( ( unsigned char )gender ) == 'M' )
{
    strcpy(s[i].Gender,"Male");
}
//...
```